# Call to props.generateRandomQuote() returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to set the Presentational component's state via a call to this.props.generateRandomQuote() but it just returns undefined. Anyone knows how to go about this? Thanks!

```
// REDUX
const RANDOM_QUOTE = 'RANDOM_QUOTE'
const quotes = [
  {
    quote: "The greatest glory in living lies not in never falling, but in rising every time we fall.",
    author: "Nelson Mandela"
  },
  {
    quote: "The way to get started is to quit talking and begin doing.",
    author: "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    quote:"Time is gold.",
    author: "Anon"
  }
];

const randomQuote = () => {
  return {
    type: RANDOM_QUOTE
  }
}

const quoteReducer = (state = quotes[0], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RANDOM_QUOTE:
      return quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const store = Redux.createStore(quoteReducer);

// REACT
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;
const connect = ReactRedux.connect;

class Presentational extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      quote: {
        quote: '',
        author: ''
      }
    }
    this.newQuote = this.newQuote.bind(this);
  }

  newQuote() {
    //this.setState ({
    // quote: this.props.generateRandomQuote();
    //});
    console.log(this.props.generateRandomQuote());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="quote-box" className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div id="text">
            <p>{this.state.quote.quote}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div id="author">
            <p>{this.state.quote.author}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-xs-3">
            <a id="tweet-quote" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet"><i className="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div className="col-xs-3">
            <a href="twitter.com/intent/tweet"><i class="fab fa-tumblr-square"></i></a>
          </div>
          <div id="new-quote" className="col-xs-6">
            <button onClick={this.newQuote}>New Quote</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {quote: state}
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      generateRandomQuote: () => {
        dispatch(randomQuote());
    }
  }
};

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Presentational);

class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppWrapper />, document.getElementById('theWhole'));
```

Hi, I am trying to set the Presentational component's state via a call to this.props.generateRandomQuote() but it just returns undefined. Anyone knows how to go about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you could split up the code by file name (put //${Filename} at the top of each code block), it would be clearer as to how your program is structured and would allow debugging the issue more easily.

I can see a couple of things that don't seem quite right however.

1. In quoteReducer you return an index in the quote array, but don't assign it to anything, it should look like this instead:

```
const quoteReducer = (state = quotes[0], action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case RANDOM_QUOTE:
      return {
      ...state, 
      randomQuote: quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

2. In mapStateToProps, you assign quote to state. In your index.js where you combineReducers, you'll assign your reducer a value (probably something like quote in this case). Given that, you should be assigning mapStateToProps like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {quote: state.quote}
};
```

I hope this helps somewhat, if you can reformat the post with slightly more structure to where each file is located in your project I could potentially provide more input.

Comment: I am doing this on codepen. I have set javascript precompiler to Babel and here are my included scripts: jquery, react, react-redux, react-dom, and redux. I did edit quoteReducer so that when action RANDOM_QUOTE is executed it will return an object containing the previous state and the randomQuote. I want the mapped state to return a quote object containing the actual quote and the author, sorry for the misleading key name. After changing my code based on your recommendation, I am still getting undefined when the RANDOM_QUOTE action is dispatched.

Comment: I think it's undefined because in your connect function you're not passing the actions. I'm not familiar with codepen, so I made a quick react app with the code you've got an uploaded it to github here: https://github.com/rfld-capco/randomQuoteRedux